# Wine - spotify - audio configuration of wine

Tags: sound, wine, configuration, spotify

I'm trying to run Spotify on Ubuntu using Wine.

I have followed the instructions on the Spotify site and I was able to run Spotify using Wine. The only thing bothering me was that I can't configure the audio options as mentioned in the tutorial.

When listening to a Song I sometimes hear a small hickup/lag in the song. It is really annoying.

The options that I have available:

[image]

The options in the tutorial:

[image]

Can someone point out what is going wrong? or any pointers how to deal with this?

Comment: This isn't an answer as much as a workaround - can you instead listen to Spotify via [play.spotify.com][1]? That's what I do.


  [1]: http://play.spotify.com

Comment: That link redirects me to: http://www.spotify.com/be-nl/video-splash/?utm_source=spotify&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=start

Comment: Are you in the Netherlands or Belgium? Can you click the 'Afspelen' link on that page? There may be some geolocation look-up going on, maybe Spotify has licensing restrictions on music via a web browser in certain countries.

Comment: Yeah, but there is no such button. In which country is this enabled you know aboout? would be nice if it was set to global. But got my spotify-unilimited working for now. Just the occasional hickups.. beats listining to the radio or youtube..

Comment: I am in the UK and I get the Afspelen button - I think it's highly likely that there are licensing restrictions on a per country basis.

Comment: Spotify is really getting on my nerves with this kind of behaviour! It the beginning I was loving Spotify, but there are soooo much things that could be better implemented/organized/.. there are really facebook alike. pff..

Comment: I think it's the record labels rather than Spotify that's the issue :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but I think that you'll find the native client is much faster and more stable than running the windows client via wine:

http://www.spotify.com/se/download/previews/

Spotify provides an apt source which you can add to your `apt.sources`, then just install via `apt-get` as usual.